# CMP ecx with DAT_

Tags: assembly, debugging

So I encountered this bit of assembly code:

```
cmp dword ptr [ECX + 0x24c], DAT_007c6bc0
```

It's comparing `ECX + 0x24c` with `DAT_007c6bc0`. If they are not equal, it will just return from the function.

I have compared the output of Ghirda and IDA (free) and in IDA it looks like this:

```
cmp dword ptr [ecx + 24Ch], offset unk_7C6BC0
```

Now, what exactly is `DAT_007c6bc0`? I couldn't really find any information on it, and how does it compare to `ECX + 0x24c` since it just checks if the address is the same, right?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `DAT_007c6bc0` (or `offset unk_7C6BC0`) is just an address in program's (virtual) address space.

Now, comparing it with `[ECX + 0x24c]`, is comparing this address with the *data located at* `ECX + 0x24c` in program's virtual address space, **not** with `ECX + 0x24c`. It's just a pointer comparison (`dword ptr` means that we treat these numbers as `dwords` - `4`bytes each); in pseudo code it could look like this:

```
if (*(ECX + 0x24c) != DAT_007c6bc0)
    return;
```

In other words, if `d` is the data located at `DAT_007c6bc0` in memory (`d = *DAT_007c6bc0`), then the code will check whether data at `ECX + 0x24c` is a pointer to `d`.